# Tag synonym: "the-avengers" to "avengers"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have two very similar Avengers-related tags:

- [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) referring to the superhero team in general, which has 169 questions.
- [the-avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-avengers) referring specifically to the 2012 Marvel film of the same name, which has 3 questions.

I don't think it's worth having these two separate tags, and that the former should be a tag synonym for the latter. The latter isn’t getting enough use, and anybody wanting to look for questions about the film have to combine the Avengers and MCU tags.

Yay or nay?

Comment: But what about [The Avengers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(TV_series))?

Answer (score 5):

I think we should have [the-avengers-2012](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-avengers-2012) for the MCU film.  [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) should then be used for the team in general (comics, TV, and film).

Comment: Is there an easy way to apply the tag to existing questions (would we want to, and without clogging up the main page), or would this just be a tag for new questions as they get asked?

Comment: @alexwlchan I need to improve this answer to address what should happen to [tag:the-avengers].  Maybe it should be the franchise tag for the MCU Avengers films...

Comment: Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: I see no point of having a tag for a single movie, when there's a tag for the universe it's set in. There are no tags for specific Harry Potter Movies, why should MCU be treated any differently.

Comment: This is now implemented. It took manually finding which questions about `avengers` were also/actually about `the-avengers-2012` and manually tagging that. As far as MrLemon's concerns, we _do_ have a policy of tagging each individual work, and tags such as Harry Potter are generally considered the exception, not the norm, because of the sheer enormity of the work involved in fixing the problem (but also, in that universe, questions are rarely limited in scope to a single book/film and instead are open to the entire franchise anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those should be synonyms.